# How to use OpenXML SDK with F# and MemoryStreams

Tags: f#, openxml

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee945362%28v=office.11%29.aspx#InMemory_UsingMemoryStream) says that you need to use resizable MemoryStreams when working with the OpenXML SDK, and the sample code works fine.

However, when I translate the sample C# code into F#, the document remains unchanged:

```
open System.IO
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing

[<EntryPoint>]
let Main args =
    let byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes "Test.docx"

    use mem = new MemoryStream()
    mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length)

    let para = new Paragraph()
    let run = new Run()
    let text = new Text("Newly inserted paragraph")
    run.InsertAt(text, 0) |> ignore
    para.InsertAt(run, 0) |> ignore

    use doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true)
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAt(para, 0) |> ignore

    // no change to the document
    use fs = new FileStream("Test2.docx", System.IO.FileMode.Create)
    mem.WriteTo(fs)

    0
```

It works fine when I use `WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test1.docx", true)`, but I want to use a `MemoryStream`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes you're making to `doc` are not reflected in MemoryStream `mem` until you close `doc`. Placing `doc.Close()` as below

```
...
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAt(para, 0) |> ignore 
doc.Close()
...
```

fixes the problem and you'll get text `Newly inserted paragraph` at the top of your `Test2.docx`.

Also your snippet is missing one required reference:

```
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
```

from `WindowsBase.dll`.

**EDIT**: as ildjarn pointed out the more F#-idiomatic would be the following refactoring:

```
open System.IO
open System.IO.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging 
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing 

[<EntryPoint>] 
let Main args = 
    let byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes "Test.docx" 

    use mem = new MemoryStream() 
    mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length) 

    do
        use doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true) 
        let para = new Paragraph() 
        let run = new Run() 
        let text = new Text("Newly inserted paragraph") 
        run.InsertAt(text, 0) |> ignore     
        para.InsertAt(run, 0) |> ignore
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAt(para, 0) |> ignore 

    use fs = new FileStream("Test2.docx", FileMode.Create) 
    mem.WriteTo(fs) 

    0
```

Comment: Personally, I would put `use doc = ...` and the following line into a `do` block rather than calling `Close()` manually.

Comment: @mcmc: In MSDN C# snippet "`doc.Close()`" is performed implicitly by `using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = ... {... }`;  [automatic disposal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.71).aspx) upon the `{...}` block exit flushes **all** `wordDoc` data to `MemoryStream`. Your initial F# port was missing this subtlety.
Refactored F# version applies the same pattern - `doc` flush happens upon leaving `do` block wrapping`use doc...` piece.